# Get Id recordset on Image Click ACCESS 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a list of projects that results from a query in source of my form.
Depending on the state of a field, I change the appearance of an image (validated or Unvalidated icon) via the controlsource of the control image. It works very well.

In a second time, on image click, I need to get the ID of the record of chosen line (DP_ID). And that's where I can not do it. Whatever line you choose, it's always the first ID I get.

PS: This function works with buttons, but the control Butoon has no ControlSource and I can not load the image of it.

[image]

Do you know a solution?

Comment: it seems that this is due to the fact that the clicked image does not take the focus, but it does not give me the solution yet! It going..

Comment: The common work-around is to place transparent buttons over the images and catch the clicks on these.